# One .env variable returns correctly but the other one is undefined in the same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dotenv, faunadb

Context: This is a React application and I want to use a .env file to store my DB related credentials. This will probably change in the future, but I can't get this working for some reason.

.env:

```
REACT_APP_FAUNA_API_KEY=**************** // returns fine if I console.log() it and I can also use it in the rest of the code
FAUNA_DB_ID=***************** // returns undefined
```

db.js:

```
import faunadb from "faunadb";

require("dotenv").config();

const client = new faunadb.Client({
  secret: process.env.REACT_APP_FAUNA_API_KEY,
  domain: "db.eu.fauna.com",
  port: 443,
  scheme: "https",
});
const q = faunadb.query;
console.log(process.env.FAUNA_DB_ID);
const databaseID = process.env.FAUNA_DB_ID;

export { client, q, databaseID };
```

Comment: Are you sure the `undefined` is not from your `console.log(process.env.ASD)`?

Comment: @Reyno whoops, I was so lost with this problem I started testing with different variable names and accidentally left in the code I copied. Thanks for pointing it out, unfortunately that's not it.

Comment: REACT_APP_FAUNA_API_KEY_KEY also has an extra "KEY".  Is that just a typo in the SO question or your code?

Comment: @ptpaterson yeah, typo, sorry, today seems to be a very long day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a CRA app (making a guess based on the `REACT_APP_FAUNA_API_KEY` variable), env vars will only be exposed to the front-end if they start with `REACT_APP_`

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

If you rename the variable to `REACT_APP_FAUNA_DB_ID`, does it return correctly?

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Somehow this piece of documentation slipped away.